# Rename columns in esttab

Tags: stata

Consider the following toy example using the *community-contributed* command `esttab`:

```
sysuse auto, clear
estpost tabstat  mpg price, statistics(count mean) columns(statistics) listwise 
esttab . , title("summary stats") cells("count(fmt(%5.0f)) mean(fmt(%5.0f))")

summary stats
--------------------------------------
                      (1)             

                    count         mean
--------------------------------------
mpg                    74           21
price                  74         6165
--------------------------------------
```

How can I change the column name from `count`  to `N`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `collabels()` option:

```
sysuse auto, clear

estpost tabstat  mpg price, statistics(count mean) columns(statistics) listwise 

esttab . , title("summary stats") collabels("N" "Mean") ///
           cells("count(fmt(%5.0f)) mean(fmt(%5.0f))")

summary stats
--------------------------------------
                      (1)             

                        N         Mean
--------------------------------------
mpg                    74           21
price                  74         6165
--------------------------------------
N                      74             
--------------------------------------
```

Comment: I had a conflict with `booktabs` adding an extra line when I used `collabels(none)` which led LaTeX to crash!